# PHP - Generate variables automatically

Tags: php, arrays, variables, for-loop, phpword

I am trying to create a statement that receives the data of a form and then generates enumerated variables (example: var1, var2, var3) and these will later be assigned to a function for use in PHPWord.

```
    <div>
      <label>Insert value</label>  
      <div>
      <input id="var1" name="var1" placeholder="Var 1" type="text"> 
      </div>
      <div>
      <input id="var2" name="var2" placeholder="Var 2" type="text"> 
      </div>
      <div>
      <input id="var3" name="var3" placeholder="Var 3" type="text"> 
      </div>
    </div> ";
```

This is my PHP:

```
for ($i=1; $i<=6; $i++){
    if(isset($_POST['var$i'])){ $var[$i] = $_POST["var$i"]; }
}
```

Insert the value of the variable in the template.

```
$templateWord->setValue('var_1',$var1);
$templateWord->setValue('var_2',$var2);
$templateWord->setValue('var_3',$var3);
```

With this I only get an error that the variable is not defined.

Comment: You can use name="var[]" and read from the array then

Comment: note that `'var$i'` will not work with single quote, use double: `"`

Comment: $var is created as array, so you should use `$templateWord->setValue('var_1',$var[1]);` an then `$var[2]` ,  `$var[3]` and so on.

Comment: Thanks for all, all worked fine.